# What book teaches you about endogenous retroviruses

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, virology, retrovirus

I'm interest in ERVs as evidence for evolution and want to learn more about them.

Answer (score 2):

The Sverdlov book is from 2005, and much work has been done in the 15 years after that. Here's a more recent review article with many useful references:
Escalera-Zamudio M, Greenwood AD. On the classification and evolution of endogenous retrovirus: humanendogenous retroviruses may not be ‘human’ after all. APMIS 2016; 124: 44–51. [PMID: 26818261](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26818261/) DOI: 10.1111/apm.12489

Comment: can you please add appropriate links (PubMed, DOI, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

*Try this one:*
[Retroviruses and Primate Genome Evolution - Eugene D. Sverdlov](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NU5ZDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Eugene+D.+Sverdlov%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Hope you find this answer helpful.